# What is wrong with my code for project Euler which throws an unsupported operand type error

Tags: python, math, fibonacci

```
numbers = [1, 2]
i = 0
while i < 4000000:
    x = int(len(numbers - 1))
    new = numbers[x] + numbers[x-1]
    if new % 2 == 0:
    numbers.append(new)
    i = new
print sum(numbers) - 1
```

The error says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 4, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'
```

Comment: brace might be at wrong place: int(len(numbers)- 1)

Comment: If you tag with the programming language, it makes it easier for potential answerers to find relevant questions to answer

Comment: len(numbers) gives you the length of the list. But len(numbers-1) is NOT valid.

Answer (score 1):

Numbers is an array, you can't subtract an integer from an array. You probably want

```
x = int(len(numbers) - 1)
```